# Using Android Jetpack Compose, is it a bad practice to define ViewModel for child composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Generally speaking, I know that defining more than a single ViewModel per screen is a bad practice. However for special use cases I found it useful.

For instance, let's consider a StatusBar Composable showing the network state. Encapsulating the ViewModel inside the Composable through Hilt injection, makes it reusable in every screen without "polluting" the screen ViewModel with network state related stuffs.

However, this breaks screen previews, because Previews in Android Studio does not works with ViewModels.

So, is that a bad practice? Would it be better to rewrite the logic in every ViewModel of each screen using that composable?

Consider the following code as an example of what I'm referring to.

```kotlin
// ViewModel.kt
@HiltViewModel
class OfflineStatusBarViewModel @Inject constructor(
    networkState: NetworkState,
) : ViewModel() {
    val isOffline = networkState.isAvailable
        .map { !it }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, WhileUiSubscribed, false)
    
}
```

```kotlin
// StatusBar.kt
@Composable
fun OfflineStatusBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: OfflineStatusBarViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val isVisible by viewModel.isOffline.collectAsState()
    if (isVisible) {
        OfflineIndicator(modifier = modifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally considered a **bad practice** to **define a ViewModel for every child composable even with hilt**. ViewModels are typically responsible for managing UI-related state and business logic.
Child composables should be concerned with displaying UI elements, not with managing state or business logic.
A **better approach is** to pass the necessary **data and callbacks** from the parent composable to the child composable. This can be done **using state hoisting or by passing the data and callbacks as parameters** to the child composable. This will make the composables **more reusable and testable**, and it will also help to **improve performance**.
So Having a ViewModel for every composable can make the codebase more complex and difficult to maintain. It can also lead to duplication of logic and data, as different ViewModels may end up managing similar information.
Also if **you don't config the Hilt correctly**, it will be recreated every time the composable is recomposed. This can **cause performance issues**, especially if the ViewModel is doing a lot of work.

This is a great article about **[App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture)** by Google, Be sure to read it.

Comment: I've read it and I agree with you. I absolutely don't want to define a ViewModel for every composable. However, in this special situation I need to share the same composable with the same behaviour in many screens. I think it's like violating the DRY principle passing down data and callbacks to the same component in the same way in every screen. Don't you? Is there a better way to share a component with the same behavior across multiple screens?

Comment: @Mirco Bellagamba Are you useing navHost to switch between screens? if yes, keep viewModel in navHost and then pass it to screens, or employ a composition-local provider to make data or dependencies available to composables within a specific scope. This approach is particularly useful when dealing with shared data that's not easily passed down through composable hierarchies.

Comment: Yes, I'm using NavHost but I was not aware about CompositionLocal provider seems to solve the organization issue I'm facing. It's definitely a better approach to this problem. For other StackOverflow users you could update the answer with this suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are trying to take with the `ViewModel` isn't very feasible. A `ViewModel` is an Android platform component so you don't want to litter your child UI components with it.

Instead, you should only inject your `ViewModel` into your top-level `**Screen` composable and pass the states from the `ViewModel` down to every other component.

You can redefine your `OfflineStatusBar` to accept a `Boolean` and pass in that property from the Screen level.

```
// StatusBar.kt
@Composable

fun OfflineStatusBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isVisible: Boolean,
) {
    if (isVisible) {
        OfflineIndicator(modifier = modifier)
    }
}
```

Now you can collect the state from the `ViewModel` somewhere inside your screen and pass down the raw value to `OfflineStatusBar`.

```
// MainScreen.kt
@Composable
fun MainAppScreen(
    viewModel: OfflineStatusBarViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
   val isVisible by viewModel.isOffline.collectAsState()
   OfflineStatusBar(isVisible = isVisible) 
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it could be a violation of DRY principle when sharing the same composable with the same logic in many screens? In every screen I need to repeat the `collectAsState` and passing down data to the composable. Is there a smarter way to do that?